# my table does not show table border and hyperlink

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

my table does not show table border and hyperlink, I am using thymeleaf and spring boot. I see the data from database when i type localhost:8080 without border, I should also see a Addbutton link in that page, but it  is not shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Management System</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class ="container my-2">


    <h1>Employees List</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/showNewEmployeeForm}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"> Add Employee </a>


    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
<table class="table table-striped border-1">
     //your table data
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It did not make a difference, can  bootstrap cause this issue?

Comment: Sorry I have missed an end quote in the first line. Did you use any CSS? Otherwise, I don't think so

Comment: I did put the right quote.No css, just some bootstrap: like this one:   <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">